# npm install try but gyp ERR

Tags: npm, gyp

I tried to install npm to convert gltf to 3d tiles, but the following error occurs.
This is the github -> https://github.com/dreamergz/gltf-to-3d-tiles

An error also occurs when using the command after running vscode as an administrator.
I am not able to solve mysql3 and gyp errors.

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

There was a phenomenon that stopped during installation, so this also cannot be installed.

I used node 16.17

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\Temp\install-6df9eb3f.cmd
npm ERR! �� �ַ���� ������Ʈ�� �� ���� �ϳ��� �����մϴ�. ���� ���带 ����Ϸ��� "/m" ����ġ�� �߰��ϼ���.
npm ERR!   unpack_sqlite_dep
npm ERR!   ������ ��θ� ã�� �� �����ϴ�.
npm ERR! C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe"��(��) ����Ǿ����ϴ�(�ڵ�: 1). [D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@16.17.1 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.2 found at "C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.28307.2094) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\3dtile\\3d-tiles-validator-main\\tools\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\userA\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.17.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\userA\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.17.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\userA\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.17.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\3dtile\\3d-tiles-validator-main\\tools\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\3dtile\\3d-tiles-validator-main\\tools\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\3dtile\\3d-tiles-validator-main\\tools\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v93-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\3dtile\\3d-tiles-validator-main\\tools\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v93-win32-x64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\3dtile\\3d-tiles-validator-main\\tools\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\3dtile\3d-tiles-validator-main\tools\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\userA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-30T01_45_55_140Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.